# How can you turn 2D faces into a 3D object?

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

This is the video I have been watching. [Blender Sword Modeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTfjrwYcY3g)

I cant figure out how the guy make the sword actually 3D, or to appear to have mass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At [4:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTfjrwYcY3g&t=269) in the video he selects all the interior faces, with circle select <kbd>C</kbd>. Then moves them along the X axis, <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>, that gives the object thickness.
Having left the outer faces unselected, it creates a bevel which when combined with the [mirror modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Mirror) he adds later will make the whole object.

[image: animated gif]

Answer (score 2):

Another quick way to do this is with a solidify modifier, used create thickness out of flat objects.

To create the sharp edges you can then add a bevel modifier.

[image]